# Uploading single files to the Appengine installation

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is it possible to upload single files to the Appengine installation instead of the full project every time. This question is related to the Java version of Appengine.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't. However the tool will upload only new/modified files.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have much control over this.

In any case, the files that haven't changed are *cloned* on the AppEngine side so it won't affect your upload time.

If you are trying to use AppEngine as a repository with "commit" operations, then consider using GoogleCode instead.

Comment: @judekm: does my answer satisfy you?